# Cannot refresh content in browser using http-server with Aurelia

Tags: express, aurelia

I'm using Aurelia with http-server, as it is described in Aurelia getting started docs. I'm unable to see changes, because any browser seems to cache entire page at first load. When I use F5, ctrl+F5 or ctrl+r, page refreshes but nothing changes, none of my modifications are visible. Then I can use another browser and at first visit changes are visible, but any subsequent visit shows always the first one. It occurs in every browser I use (Chrome and Firefox, ever in private mode). I'm certain that it is not bug in Aurelia itself.

I tried to change port and use http-server with -c parameter. Nothing changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a caching issue that pops up sometimes with http-server.  I don't know exactly what causes it but I believe the `-c` modifier changes the length of cache-control so I would set that as `0` or `1` instead of assigning a port that way.

Comment: I mean I use -p (for port) and -c (for cache). I was using -c with 1 and -1 (as it states in docs as disabling). I just tried -c 0 and it helped! But it must be first run, otherwise cache would be working. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force your Aurelia app to be constantly refreshed after you modify it, you can have a look at the following thread:

https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/94

Aaike commented on 8 May 2015:

> change your index.html to add the extension right before you import
>   the aurelia-bootstrapper

```
<script>
      var systemLocate = System.locate;
      System.locate = function(load) {
        var System = this;
        return Promise.resolve(systemLocate.call(this, load)).then(function(address) {
          if(address.lastIndexOf("html.js") > -1) return address;
          if(address.lastIndexOf("css.js") > -1) return address;
          return address + System.cacheBust;
        });
      };
      System.cacheBust = '?bust=' + Date.now();

      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
</script>
```

Comment: This is the same trick that I found at: `http://vadosware.com/2015/05/17/cache-busting-with-systemjsaurelia/` is there any other preferred method besides this, is it a known problem and how could we get better control over caching. I'm new to Aurelia and SystemJS. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.